# I want a result set by joining two tables which are in two different databases or two different context c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, .net-core

Databases are oracle..

Example :
student table in connectionstring1,
class table in connectionstring2

Want to join student and class table using uniq column studentid and return result

I want this achieved in studentgetmethod();

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing how your contexts or classes are this is a very general answer, but something like the following might work:

```
var students = (from s in studentContext.Students
            select s).ToList();
var classes = (from c in classContext.Classes
            select c).ToList();

var classStudents = (from s in students
               join c in classes on s.StudentID equals c.StudentID
               where *any conditions*
               select *fields or entities you care about*);
```

The classStudents variable could be a typed class you make or an existing one from your contexts, it could even be an anonymous type.

You might also look at the following examples: https://entityframework.net/joining

Comment: Have you tried this? I don't believe it is legal to attempt a join across different contexts.

Comment: You're probably right, its been a long time since I connected 2 contexts. I've edited the answer to fix this.